# Merge 2 views in sql

Tags: sql, database

So I have two views with the same data structure. Num is a type of int. I want the num with the same id add up together. I don't think union can do this kind of merge. Can anyone help me with it?

View1:

```
 id   | num |
-------+-----+
     A |   4 |
     B |   6 |
     C |   7 |
```

View2:

```
 id   | num |
-------+-----+
     A |   1 |
     D |   2 |
     C |   3 |
```

expected View:

```
 id   | num |
-------+-----+
     A |   5 |
     B |   2 |
     C |  10 |
     D |   2 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Z.id,SUM(Z.num) AS num
  FROM
(
SELECT * FROM View1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM View2
) Z
GROUP BY Z.id
ORDER BY Z.id;
```

Comment: Does `(
SELECT * FROM View1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM View2
) Z` means we union everything from View 1 and View 2 into a view called Z?

Comment: Its not exactly the SQL view but UNION ALL will get all the rows with similar columns from 'n' tables or views. In this case it is defined as an inline view. On top of this u can do your work needed..

Comment: Pls accept the answer if u are satisfied with it. thanks.